# Pre render javascript elements in ASP.NET Core

Tags: reactjs, angular, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core. I have previously used ASP.NET Framework. I plan to use my old website layout (ASP.NET MVC) and migrate it to ASP.NET Core, but when I came to implement server-side rendering, I have found that the tools I was using are no longer being maintained (ReactJS.Net).

My current site contains server side rendered React components, that I created using ReactJS.NET. I have dynamic parts inside my site where the content changes based on the actions of users. To keep my site fast my site is not a React SPA (single page application). If I move to a SPA, I will have to architect the entire site again.

My question is: what is the best way to have dynamic elements in my site but have them prerender on the server, ideally using ASP.NET Core?